# How do I get "this" to reference a Class instead of an html button during onlick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I made a Stopwatch class in JavaScript, and when a user clicks on a "start stopwatch" button, the stopwatch should start.

My problem is that when a user clicks the "start stopwatch" button, `this` is referencing the button instead of the Stopwatch object.

Any suggestions?

Here is an example:
https://c9.io/rjfreund/stopwatch/workspace/stopwatch.html

Comment: please show your code right here. nobody wants to go and dig through your website

Comment: Javascript doesn't have classes. It has prototype-based objects. And, yes, `this` will represent the button. Store a reference to some other object if that's what you want to use.

Comment: .. and don't post an entire program. Post a _testcase_.

Comment: @lbu Thanks. Will do for next time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll post a testcase next time. This is my first post here.

Comment: @RJFreund: Well really it should be something you did in debugging before even thinking of posting online :) If you're not considering adding one into _this_ question, then we should delete it, as it will be of no help to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...use `.bind()` or `.on()` to bind the handler, and set the object in the *event-data*.

```
$('.yourElement').on("click", {obj: yourObject}, function(event) {
    alert(event.data.obj);
});
```

Comment: If the OP doesn't mention jQuery, it's usually best to go with vanilla Javascript.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: OP's code uses jQuery. If you bother to look at it you'll see :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Still you made a valid point since it isn't exactly clear in the question. I updated my answer to include the script element being used on the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do without code:

```
<a id="start_stopwatch" onclick="yourStopwatchClass.start.call(yourStopwatchClass)">Start stopwatch!</a>
```

`call` refers the `this` variable to whatever you pass in, in this case your `Stopwatch` class.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take this into account, although I prefer not to write in-line JavaScript if avoidable.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a function's `this` is set by how the function is called. For a listener, if assigned like:

```
element.onclick = instance.method;
```

then it will be called by the handler more or less as a method of the element, setting its `this` to the element. Attaching the listener using other methods (`addEventListener` and  various library schemes) do the same thing.

You can use [`call`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) or [`apply`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3), but you can also wrap the function and call it to set `this` to the object you want:

```
element.onclick = funciotn() {insance.method()};
```

You can also use [`bind`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5), which is provided by ES5, various libraries and [shims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).